# Parameter Generic Inference With keyof

Tags: typescript, generics, discriminated-union

I am attempting to use a function parameter to infer the keyof a narrowed generic type of another function parameter. If I hardcode a class type in place of the generic everything seems to work; however, when using a generic value the narrowing of the second parameter does not work. Been at for a couple of days now, I am at a lost.

Confused? I know I am... Here is the code to illustrate the problem. In the last function, the second parameter should resolve as a valid property.

```
class A {
    readonly shortname = 'A';
    id: number;
    genStart: Date;
}

class B {
    readonly shortname = 'B';
    id: number;
    genPart: Date;
}


class C {
    readonly shortname = 'C';
    id: number;
    genEnd: Date;
}

type Entities = A | B | C;

type GetEtType<T extends Entities['shortname']>
    =  keyof Extract<Entities, { shortname: T }>;

class EtTester {
    tester<TShortName extends Entities['shortname'],
        TProp extends GetEtType<TShortName>>(shortName: TShortName,
        propName: TProp) {

    }
}

let et = new EtTester();

et.tester('B', 'genPart' )
```

Any assistance would be great.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20shortname%20%3D%20'A'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20genStart%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20shortname%20%3D%20'B'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20genPart%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20shortname%20%3D%20'C'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20genEnd%3A%20Date%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Entities%20%3D%20A%20%7C%20B%20%7C%20C%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20GetEtType%3CT%20extends%20Entities%5B'shortname'%5D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%20%20keyof%20Extract%3CEntities%2C%20%7B%20shortname%3A%20T%20%7D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20EtTester%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20tester%3CTShortName%20extends%20Entities%5B'shortname'%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TProp%20extends%20GetEtType%3CTShortName%3E%3E(shortName%3A%20TShortName%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20propName%3A%20TProp)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20et%20%3D%20new%20EtTester()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aet.tester('B'%2C%20'genPart'%20)%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem properly, `GetEtType<T>` should return keys of the entity type selected by its generic type parameter `T` which must be one of `shortname` values defined in each entity.

`keyof Extract<...>` does not work, it seems that `keyof` is applied eagerly at some time in the conditional type evaluation when it resolves to `never`.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599951/typescript-generically-infer-union-type-member-based-on-a-string-literal-proper), which tells how to select a member of discriminated union type based on the type of discriminant property, here is a definition for `GetEtType` which works here:

```
type GetEtType<T extends Entities['shortname']>
    = Entities extends (infer E)? 
        E extends Entities?
            E['shortname'] extends T ? keyof E : never : never : never
;
```