# Typescript: in a HOF, infer type of callback arg given a specific string

Tags: typescript

In the following snippet, how can I define `subscribe` such that given a specific event name (e.g. "NamedEvent") the callback argument, `event`, has a correctly inferred `Event` type?

```
type EventName = "NamedEvent" | "OtherEvent";

type Event = {
  name: "NamedEvent",
  data: { a: number, b: string }
} | {
  name: "OtherEvent",
  data: { c: string, d: number }
}

subscribe("NamedEvent", (event) => {
  ...
});
```

Ideally in the callback, Typescript would infer that the event provided is specifically the one with the matching name, "NamedEvent", and cannot be any other one. I've tried to implement this several times with no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: generically infer union type member based on a string literal property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599951/typescript-generically-infer-union-type-member-based-on-a-string-literal-proper)

Comment: @Blackhole, that post did help me narrow down what the best approach is, which I've answered below, but didn't fully answer my question. It was helpful though, so thanks!

I went ahead and added my answer on that post as well, as I think it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and Typescript behaves exactly as it should:
[image]

You don't even need `type EventName` as this information is redundant.

Comment: My intention is not to hardcode event names inside the `subscribe` implementation. Also the `subscribe` is supposed to accept a callback as it's second argument, then invoke the callback with the matching event (determined by the first argument, eventName).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the `Extract<Type, Union>` utility type today, so this is more or less what I came up with:

```typescript
const subscribe<N extends Event['name']>(
  eventName: N,
  callback: (event: Extract<Event, { name: N }>) => void
) => {
  // business logic...
  callback(event)
}
```

From the Typescript documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

> Constructs a type by extracting from `Type` all union members that are assignable to `Union`.